# NativeScript Directions plugin using nativescript

Tags: google-maps, typescript, google-api, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm pretty new to app development scene and I am starting my journey with nativescript. For my first app I'm trying to implement a googlemaps api in my app.

But when i try to run the demo that's included with the plugin or try to implement it into my app, I keep getting the same error *(the pictures below)*.

I've got no clue what the cause of it is and can't find any solution to it.

Has anyone had the same problem or can anyone clarify what the source of the problem is?

A sincere thank you in advance

**Problem**

I keep getting the following errors.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/24669227/21487765/20ca9b92-cbd3-11e6-82f5-8b90fe072772.png]

[image]

**source of plugin**

"https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-directions"

Comment: Does that require Google Play Services ?

Comment: Yes, but I''ve got that installed, the default google maps on the phone works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you haven't done a full build since adding the plugin, only livesynced changes. Try readding the platform folders and do a "tns run ios/android".